# # symbol chopping the URL text Flask Application

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am using the following code to display the text on my browser:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response, request    
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/v1.0/qanda/', methods=['GET'])

def people_api():
    text = request.args.get('text'.replace('#',' ' ))
    if text is None:
           make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Missing text parameter'}), 400)
    return text
app.run()
```

When I tried this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1.0/qanda/?text=adam is my name
```

I got the output as:

```
adam is my name
```

But when I tried this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1.0/qanda/?text=adam# is my name
```

I got the output as:

```
adam
```

I tried to replace the `#` symbol but it didn't work. I want to know, if I want to display my text in the browser using the above URL what I need to do? I want to display the complete text but only because of the `#` symbol this problem is arising, is what I suppose. Kindly, suggest me.

Comment: Put quotes around the URL text?

Comment: @cricket_007 where in the browser? then it is not working.

Comment: Well, Fragment identifiers aren't passed to the server, AFAIK. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752995/how-to-get-access-to-the-url-segments-after-a-in-python-flask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why non existing URL containing the sharp ("#") sign in Python/Flask aren't handled by the errorhandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705285/why-non-existing-url-containing-the-sharp-sign-in-python-flask-arent-hand)

Comment: You could do `text=adam%23+is+my+name`... So, encoding the data

Comment: @cricket_007 So does that means that there is no solution for such a problem?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have a lot of data and do not know where the `#` symbol will appear. How I can make it. The line mentioned in question is just an example.

Comment: I don't know what problem you have. Whatever client you are using must url encode anything passed over to the API. For example, spaces should not be in a URL. That must be replaced with plus or `%20`

Comment: If you are sending data, you most likely want a POST request, not a GET request with URL parameters

Answer (score 1):

**You can not put `#` as value in request parameter as like `?`, `&`, `/`, `&`, `=`**

If you really want to send `#` as in value of request parameter then you have to make it [URL encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to reach it to the server. Otherwise it will never reach to the server as you are expecting.

For encode of `#` you have to use `%23`.

As your requesting URL should be like `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1.0/qanda/?text=adam%23 is my name`

Answer (score 0):

The `#` symbol, like `?` `/`, `&` and `=` has special meaning when used as part of the URL.

The `#` specifically is for identifying a named anchor in HTML; so the browser will not send it as part of the request.

Stick with space, or URL encode the string before you submit it.